# How to set remove and persist cascade in symfony 3 Mongodb reference many

Tags: mongodb, cascading-deletes, persist, cascading, symfony3.x

In my project Im using symfony 3 and Mongodb.
I have two documents Role and Privilege , one role contains multiple privileges, and one privilege has multiple roles.(ReferenceMany)
how to put delete and persist in cascade.